# Definition of Additive Loop

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, binary-operations, quasigroups

I have thought of loops as having the operations of multiplication and left and right division. I read the D. R. Hughes article on [Additive and Multiplicative Loops of Planar Ternary Rings](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9cc3/8ec4a52e28021a855fabee9dc8de6b5e438c.pdf) and it contains:

> We define addition in $R$ by $a + b = F(1, a, b)$, and multiplication by $ab = F(a, b, 0)$. Then the set $R$, under addition, forms a loop with *identity* $0$, and the set $R^*$ of nonzero elements of $F$, under multiplication, forms a loop with identity $1$ ... These loops are called the additive and multiplicative loops, respectively.

The article seems to build a ring from the loops and a set with multiplication and addition defined for it fits with my understanding of rings. I have searched for "additive loop" and found it used in many articles though none have clarified my understanding of the term "loop" as addition relates to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop is a set with some binary operation on it which satisfies some axioms.  That binary operation is usually called "multiplication" but that's just a name.  In particular, it's perfectly fine to instead call it "addition" if that makes sense in a certain context.  So, that's all that's going on here: there is an operation called "addition" on the set $R$ and we're using it as the operation for a loop structure on $R$.  We then refer to this loop as the "additive loop" of $R$ to distinguish it from other loop structures we might have relating to $R$.